# Unable upload file xls and csv in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-2, mime-types

I have error "upload_invalid_filetype" everytime I upload file in xls and csv format. It just work fine for file with xlsx, docx and pdf. I know that it has something to do with Mimes.php. I tried everything I found in the internet to get it work but still no luck. Here I put the mime content so maybe you can find what I missed.

```
'csv'   =>  array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel','application/zip'),
'xls'   =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document','application/excel', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/msexcel','application/zip'),
```

Answer (score 0):

if your `xls` and `csv` is the problem then try this in `mime.php`

```
'xls'   =>  array('application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/msexcel', 'application/x-msexcel', 'application/x-ms-excel', 'application/x-excel', 'application/x-dos_ms_excel', 'application/xls', 'application/x-xls', 'application/excel', 'application/download', 'application/vnd.ms-office', 'application/msword'),
'csv'   =>  array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain'),
```

also while uploading try this

```
$randomString = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($x = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', ceil(10 / strlen($x)))), 1, 10);
        $config['upload_path'] = $YOUR_PATH;
        $config['file_name'] = $randomString;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'csv|CSV|xls|XLS';
        $config['overwrite'] = 0;
        $config['max_size'] = 2048;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config); // Make sure it has been initialized
```

also try to loaded the library in the construct, or right after the upload part

```
$this->load->library('excel');
```

this will only upload the xls and csv file, you have to read the file after upload you will have to follow the documentation of excel library